# Is it better to use dictionary or individually bind every variable in Model (More detail in description)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, view

I want to populate all the label text of my application from back end. I have an estimation of 60 labels per page. Is it better to save all the data in the form of a dictionary and and move it to the view or should I create a variable for each of this labels and bind them in the Model and pass as an object.

Which one is better in terms of speed and memory usage?

EDIT 1:

> I'm refraining from using resx, since there would be frequent changes in the labels and I don't want to republish the code frequently.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, one of the best practices is to use resource files (.resx) and take advantage of [Globalization and Localization features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2) provided by the framework.

Resource files are sort of dictionary, but you will be able to benefit from a lot more than doing it by yourself.

Hope it helps.